# How to replace values of a list with values of another list based on index

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, indexing

I am wondering if I can replace values of a list with elements of another list based on the index in Python:

let's say

```
a=[3, 2, 8, 7, 0]
d=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

I want to replace the elements of list a with the elements of list d. Values of list a define the index number of list d.

I want a list like c,

```
c=['d','c','i','a']
```

Comment: Better to think in terms of making a new list than replacing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So, there is a calculation for a single element, from `a`, which consists of using that element as an index into `d`. Clearly we know how to write that: by indexing with `[]`. The next trick is to repeat that calculation for the elements of `a`, and collect them into `c`. Please see the linked duplicate for this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this manner: (anyway I am curious if there is another, simplest way)

```
c=[]
a=[3, 2, 8, 7, 0]
d=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
for index in a:
    c.append(d[index])

print(c)
```

result: c = ['d', 'c', 'i', 'h', 'a']

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [3,2,8,7,0]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
l = [b[i] for i in a]
# d, c, i, a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[3, 2, 8, 7, 0]
d=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
d = np.array(d)
d[[a]]
```

This can be done with the help of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__getitem__` with `map` which is quite faster.

```
list(map(d.__getitem__, a))
```

```
Output >> ['d', 'c', 'i', 'h', 'a']
```